# Save language chosen by user, Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, manifest, lang

How can I change default string.xml? I can change my app to five different languages, but whenever I close the app and reopen it. It goes back to default English.

Is it possible to somehow change the default folder "values". For example, from values (English) which is default to values-pt (Portuguese).

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use following

```
public void loadLocale() {
        String langPref = "Language";
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs",
                Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String language = prefs.getString(langPref, "");
        changeLang(language);
    }

public void changeLang(String lang) {
        if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            return;
        myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        saveLocale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
        config.locale = myLocale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    }

public void saveLocale(String lang) {
        String langPref = "Language";
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs",
                Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(langPref, lang);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

and in onCreate()

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_language);
        loadLocale();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ganpat, I tried your solution and it kinda of worked. The main menu and other activities are in a different language, but the buttons and textviews on the main activity are still in English. Pretty weird. It's like the app loads the main activity (textviews and buttons) in the default language English, then change the language to whatever the user selected(Portuguese-pt). So, everything else is Portuguese.

Comment: I think I fixed, but not sure if it's the best way. I put "loadLocale();" before "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);"  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Haha! This answer saved my day. Appreciate so much, @Ganpat Kaliya

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

To Change:

```
public void changeLanguage(String language) {
    locale = new Locale(language);
    saveLocale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    conf.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, null);
    updateText();
}
```

To Save:

```
    public void saveLocale(String language) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("com.example.myapp.PREFERENCES", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("USER_LANGUAGE", language);
    editor.commit();
}
```

To Update:

```
    private void updateText() {
    btn_chat.setText(R.string.live_chat);
}
```

To Load:

```
public void LoadLanguage(){
    SharedPreferences shp = getSharedPreferences(
            "com.example.myapp.PREFERENCES",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = shp.getString("USER_LANGUAGE","");
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

In MainActivity you can check the default language that app is using:

```
language = getResources().getString(R.string.lang);
```

Then if the language is the language you want by check with statement, you should perform `updateText()` function:

```
if (language.equals("zh")) {
        btn_lang.setText(R.string.someName);
        updateText();
    }
```

Do not forget to perform the `LoadLanguage()` in MainActivity to Load the language that user saved.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that works for me:

```
public class  MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static String storeLang;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SharedPreferences shp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    storeLang = shp.getString(getString(R.string.key_lang), "");

    // Create a new Locale object
    Locale locale = new Locale(storeLang);

    // Create a new configuration object
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    // Set the locale of the new configuration
    config.locale = locale;
    // Update the configuration of the Accplication context
    getResources().updateConfiguration(
            config,
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
    );

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

}

Source: https://blog.lokalise.co/android-app-localization/

Comment: Hi Til. Thanks for your answer. But can you please explain how this code solves the problem? [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, apparently, I incorrectly translated the question from English

Answer (score 0):

You can write to, then read from `SharedPreferences` to manage the user's chosen language

To save:

```
SharedPreferences shp = getSharedPreferences(
        "com.example.yourapp.PREFERENCES",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shp.edit();
editor.putString("USER_LANGUAGE", language);
editor.commit();
```

To load:

```
SharedPreferences shp = getSharedPreferences(
        "com.example.yourapp.PREFERENCES",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String language = shp.getString("USER_LANGUAGE","en");
```

When you load the language, modify the locale to use it

```
Locale locale = new Locale(language);  
Locale.setDefault(locale); 
Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
config.locale = locale; 
getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, I would like to save just like you showed me using SharedPreferences. But after saving it, it would automatically choose the new default language when opening the app again. For example, if I changed to portuguese, when I reopen the app, all strings would automatically be retrieved from values-pt, string.xml

Comment: Thank you for the help Andrew. I have fixed my issue with Ganpta's solution.