# Store Language Locality in Preference

Tags: android

Creating app in which I am using **language locality** for english and Spanish on login screen.Once user is login the entire app will work based on their language selection. And its working correctly.

But now I have remember me checkbox, when checkbox is clicked, user will not switch on login screen, it'll switch directly on home screen and app should be work on their language selection. I **know for this I have to store language in shared preference** but I don't know how to store particular language in preference.

```
if ((PreferenceClass.getBooleanPreferences(LoginActivity.this, Constant.IS_LOGIN))) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashBoardActivity.class));
        finish();
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        mContext = this;
        init();
    }


init(){
mEnglishBox = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxLEnglish);
    mEnglishBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    mSpanishBox = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxLSpanish);
    mSpanishBox.setOnClickListener(this);

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                PreferenceClass.setBooleanPreference(mContext, Constant.IS_LOGIN, true);

            } else {
                PreferenceClass.setBooleanPreference(mContext, Constant.IS_LOGIN, false);
            }
        }
    });}




public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.checkBoxLEnglish:
            isEnglish = true;
            mEnglishBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00DB00"));
            mSpanishBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            setLocaleLanguage(mContext, "en");


            break;
        case R.id.checkBoxLSpanish:
            isEnglish = false;
            mSpanishBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00DB00"));
            mEnglishBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            setLocaleLanguage(mContext, "es");

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}


public void setLocaleLanguage(Context context, String lang) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    setUIForLanguage();
}
```

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813934/save-language-chosen-by-user-android

Answer (score 1):

Could have something like following (in Settings class for example)

```
private final SharedPreferences preferences;

public void setSelectedLanguage(String selectedLanguageCpde) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, selectedLanguageCpde);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getSelectedLanguage() {
    return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, "en");
}
```

Comment: I don't see use of the above code in your updated solution.