# How change language into android application using button, config.locale = locale @Deprecated

Tags: android, locale

I've create one layout with two image button. I want change language when button is pressed.

I've create res-values-it and res-values-en, now I can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change language programmatically in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942535/using-locale-to-force-android-to-use-a-specific-strings-xml-file-for-a-non-suppo

Comment: config.locale = locale @Deprecated and I can't use it!! i don't know i can I do!!

Comment: So? If you're under API level 24 use `config.locale = locale`. For API 24+ use `setLocales(LocaleList)` as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#locale)

Comment: I'm Api 21!! is deprecated! I'm using Eclipse..

Comment: :)) If you're on API 21, how come it's deprecated? :)

Comment: Sorry, I haved min sdk= 21 and api level 25. It's my fault! thaks!

Comment: `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        config.locale = locale;
}
else {
       // use API for 24+
}`

Answer (score 1):

i used this one for french

```
 String languageToLoad  = "fr_FR";
     Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
     Locale.setDefault(locale);
     Configuration config = new Configuration();
     config.locale = locale;
     context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

Intent intent = new Intent(XYZ.this, XYZ.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but config.locale = locale @Deprecated and don't function, why?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add a settings Menu in wich user can select language that will be stored as a `SharedPreference`. then when displaying text you have to get language from `SharedPreferences` and use conditions to select text from `res-values-it` or `res-values-en` . i guess that should be usefull.

Comment: Have you any example please?

Comment: @Ormet you can find help over here : [Save language chosen by user, Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813934/save-language-chosen-by-user-android)

Comment: @ Boubakr Echieb 
I've solved, but when I rotate the screen I loose locate, why??